# negative interrogative forms in present simple and continuous

Tags: grammar

my question is about forming negative questions in present simple and continuous, I have got some confusion here:

as you know, there is a special case when it comes to tag questions with subject I

for instance we ask with the form: aren't I?

does this apply to present simple questions?
do we say: aren't I a teacher? for instance..

and in present continuous:

am I not going to the party?

or, should it be like:

aren't I going to the party?

thanks

Comment: In conversation, _aren't I_ is quite common, and _ain't I_ is probably even more common. In writing, tag questions are rarely used, and the same for first-person-subject questions, so you don't need to worry about writing them.